# How can I best record and improve my pre-shoot planning process?

Tags: lighting, workflow, learning, studio-setup, posing

When planning a photo shoot, I often find myself making lighting/posing diagrams on scratch paper, but they end up in the trash after the shoot.
After most shoots, I try to document each shoot in One-Note, so that I can go back and learn from what worked and what didn't, but I cannot find a good way to get my lighting/posing diagrams into it.

My ideal workflow would involve a process, preferably digital where I could sketch out my ideas, then later go back and update them with what actually happened during the shoot, and some notes to reflect upon the process, maybe even link to completed images.

I've looked at several different packages, but nothing seems to really fit, but I cannot believe that I am unique in this need.

Comment: @mattdm I struggled with the survey of what people do, versus asking for a product recommendation.  I took a shot at rewriting the question a bit, still not sure its much better.

Answer (score 2):

What about starting a blog?

You could document your pre-shoot notes, then add some set up shots, and finally some of the resulting shots.

Not only does it document your learning process, it's there for others to learn from too. Plus you can get feedback through the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a wiki for keeping track or your notes and organising things. It would handle images which you could generate by either photographing your sketches or using some other software.

You could go as far as drawing reusable components in illustrator and simply plonking them in the right position and exporting it to .svg when you need.

https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:owncloud